# Making a new list with enumerate and sorting

Tags: python

I am brand new to python and coding in general. I'm actually a Cinema 4D artist. C4D has a built in python script manager. I will do my best to explain what I'm trying for.

I have a sphere. The sphere is broken up into points. I have calculated the distance each point on the sphere is away from a different object. I have made a list of all these calculated distances. I would like to make a new array of the index and the corresponding distance calculation. How do I combine the two lists into a new array? Mock example below -

```
def main():
    pointdistance = [150.2, 2.3, 5.5, 145.2, 30.4, 22]
    indices = list(range(len(pointdistance)))

    print indices
```

It returns the correct number of indices needed [0,1,2,3,4,5]
my desired result would look like a combination - something like this:

```
preweight = [(0,150.2)(1,2.3)(2,5.5)(3,145.2)(4,30.4)(5,22)]
```

For bonus I would like to dynamically sort the new "preweight" array based on the distance calculation. So as I move the object around the array sorts from closest point to furtherest point. Kinda like this:

```
postweight = [(1,2.3)(2,5.5)(5,22)(4,30.4)(3,145.2)(1,150.2)]
```

Thanks in advance. I am really enjoying the help this site provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate(..)`. When called on a list and iterated over, it returns elements of the list as a tuple of `(index, element)`.

For the second half of your question, use `sorted(.., key=<func>)`. `sorted(..)` when called with a `key=` will use the value returned by the function applied on the item for  sorting. In your specific case, `<func>` would be something that would take an element and return the second item of the tuple. Something like: `lambda x: x[1]`

```
>>> pointdistance = [150.2, 2.3, 5.5, 145.2, 30.4, 22]
>>> list(enumerate(pointdistance))
[(0, 150.2), (1, 2.3), (2, 5.5), (3, 145.2), (4, 30.4), (5, 22)]
>>> sorted(enumerate(pointdistance), key=lambda x: x[1])
[(1, 2.3), (2, 5.5), (5, 22), (4, 30.4), (3, 145.2), (0, 150.2)]
```

Comment: Just a pedantic note ... enumerate does not "return a new list"

Comment: Wow thanks for the speedy response. I greatly appreciate your help. So far this seems to be perfect. Now I'll spend all next week trying to implement this data into a practical animation and come back with some C4D specific python questions I am sure.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Thanks so much! Should I ask a follow up question in a new thread? Or is there a better approach to follow ups?

Comment: You can, as comments here, unless it isn't off the main topic.

Comment: Note: Not everyone agrees, but it's (mildly) faster, and IMO, generally a good idea to avoid `lambda` functions when built-ins are available to do it for you. `from operator import itemgetter`, then use `key=itemgetter(1)` for `sorted`. My reason for avoiding `lambda` is that `lambda`, being infinitely flexible, can be used for tricky things, and I reserve them for that; if I need to do something tricky, I use `lambda` as a cue to myself & maintainers that I shouldn't gloss over what I'm doing, it might be weird. I use the builtins to say "I'm not doing anything tricky, feel free to skip".

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right, I don't agree ;). I prefer lambdas like that for two reasons: a) I get to know its job precisely by looking at the expression. It isn't complicated to me, personally (as long as I can keep it readable). b) I'm lazy; hate to go to the top, import, come back down.. :P

Comment: My problem comes in when the situation gets more complicated. If I'm sorting by indices 3, then 4, then 1, `itemgetter(3, 4, 1)` remains obvious/short. `lambda x: (x[3], x[4], x[1])` is uglier, and more importantly, can be confused with `lambda x: (x[3], -x[4], x[1])` (note how we negate `x[4]`; we wanted a descending numeric sort). By only using `lambda` for the latter, I reduce the risk of glossing over that all important `-`; by using `itemgetter` for the simple case, I know it's not the complex one. That make more sense as a rationale?

Comment: For multiple items or any similar complexities, yes `itemgetter` is way better than a lambda, I agree -- I'd use it too. For a simple item, as in this question, I tend to stick with a simple lambda.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [SuperSaiyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38003807/3159288), the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) provides a more robust tool for solving all similar problems. While `enumerate` simply pairs a list of elements with their indexes automatically, `zip` requires that you provide a series of iterables that it will group together:

```
obj_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
obj_values = [1, 4, 7, 3]

paired = zip(obj_labels, obj_values)

print(paired) # gives: [('a', 1), ('b', 4), ('c', 7), ('d', 3)]

ordered = sorted(paired, key=lambda pair: pair[1])
print(ordered) # gives: [('a', 1), ('d', 3), ('b', 4), ('c', 7)]
```

However `zip` also allows you to do some other cool things like grouping more than two iterables, and "unzipping" a list elements that are equal length pairs. Continuing from the previous example:

```
# we can "unzip" our pairs like this
unzipped = zip(*paired)
# they come out as tuples
l1 = list(unzipped[0])
l2 = list(unzipped[1])

# check that we've unzipped
assert l1 == obj_labels
assert l2 == obj_values

# add more data to our paired list
obj_indexes = range(len(obj_values))

paired_len3 = zip(obj_labels, obj_indexes, obj_values)
ordered_len3 = sorted(paired_len3, key=lambda pair: pair[2])
print(ordered_len3) # gives: [('a', 0, 1), ('d', 3, 3), ('b', 1, 4), ('c', 2, 7)]
```

Comment: Oh this is a really interesting feature! Thank you! It harps on what my follow up question would be. I'll try to explain it thoughtfully PS: I'm sorry this is my first time on the site and I can't seem to figure out how to add code into the comments: I would like to combine the Distance variable with a global position Vector.

So an example array would look something like this - 

pointA = [22.5,Vector(100,100,100)]

And then can I unzip this to access just the Vector value?

Comment: Write \`<my code>\` and it will render as `<my code>`. When answering a question tagged with a particular language, it will automatically add syntax highlighting (to force highlighting [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)).

Comment: As for your vector question, yes. If `v_i` is a vector and `d_i` is a distance for `i` in `[1, 2, ... n]`, and we have `pairs = [(d_1, v_1), (d_2, v_2), ... (d_n, v_n)]` we can use `zip` to separate the vectors and distances with `distances, vectors = zip(*pairs)` (but remember `distances` and `vectors` come out as tuples, not lists).

Comment: Thanks so much! This is great. I am getting an <AssertionError> when trying to <unzipped = zip(*ordered)> . Is there a reason for this? Or could my syntax be wrong?

Comment: Oh i think I understand! The "assert" is checking to see if obj_dis and l2 are exactly the same. But they are not == because obj_dis is "unsorted" and l2 is "sorted". Thanks again Whiskey! You have been very helpful!